# Labels overlapping in UITableViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

We are moving away from objective c and implementing the new code in Swift. I am facing problems with UITableViewCells. Whenever I add content in the cell and use UITableView to display it, the content of the cell gets cluttered. How do I prevent the "ques" "ans" label from overlapping?

Output when I run the app:

[image]

The class controller goes like:

```
@objc public class ProfileViewController :UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTableView: UITableView! //connected to storyboard
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.detailTableView.delegate = self;
        self.detailTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.detailTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DetailTableViewCell")
    }

    public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

DetailTableViewCell class

```
@objc public class DetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    public override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    public override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }   
}
```

Xib of cell class

[image: xib view of cell class]

storyboard view of controller

[image: storyboard view of controller]

I believe there is something very obvious I am missing out because I defined all the constraints accurately. Can I please get some hints?

Comment: Have you set constraints on the UITableview itself?

Comment: I would suggest you to use Prototype cells and do away with cell.xib once and for all.

Comment: @MattRees yes I have defined a definite height, leading, trailing and vertical spacing constraints.

Comment: @GeneCode Swift doesn't support xibs as expected?

Comment: You just give constraints to your cel

Comment: @JitendraModi What constraints exactly?

Comment: @AsthaGupta Swift and objective C both supports xib well, you just have to use it in proper way

Comment: search about autolayout in ios you will get your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143962/discussion-between-jitendra-modi-and-astha-gupta).

Comment: You have a two leading constraints for your `ans` label.   Remove the ans.leading = leading+132

Comment: @Paulw11 There is no issue there. Using ans.leading, I have defined ques.trailing. So think of it like this - defined question leading and answer leading. Now, question should end where answer starts and hence, the constraint relating ques.trailing and ans.leading

Comment: You have constrained and to both the trailing of ques and to the leading of the content view. You want one or the other

Comment: @Paulw11 - It's more like, I limited the trailing value of ques depending on answer's leading value. Hence, there is no conflict. If there had been, xCode would have highlighted that :) In fact, if I delete any one of those, xcode turns red

Comment: @JitendraModi I went through an overview of layout. To me it seems that its a synonym of defining everything using constraints and I have done that.

Comment: Adjust your cell height and y position of label, and check it.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing the right files?  Your class name and your downcast in `cellForRow(at:)` are different. Since you are using storyboard I would also suggest you use prototype cells rather than xib files

Comment: Thanks for pointing that you. I updated the code. The files shown are correct

Comment: You certainly have too many constraints.  You should delete the bottom constraints, since the height of the label is implied by the font size, so you only need to constrain the top (or you can constrain the bottom and let the top work out automatically).  Similarly, only constrain the leading of `ans` to the trailing of `ques` - The red errors you get when you delete the leading+145 are because you need to set content hugging if you constrain both leading and trailing - otherwise autolayout can't figure out which of the two text fields to resize.

Comment: Implemented prototype cell and that worked fine. I guess I will move forward with this approach from now onwards

Comment: @AsthaGupta good job sir. glad it worked out for you.